# Alignment one cell in h:panelGrid

Tags: html, css, jsf-2

How to align a particular cell inside a `h:panelGrid` in jsf 2.0. I am able to align whole table by adding style in the `h:panelGrid`. But I need only one cell to be aligned center.

Thanks
Brajesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to say that you need only one column (through the word `cell`) to be aligned center, use columnClasses

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="basicStyle, centerStyle, basicStyle"
```

CSS

```
.basicStyle {
    /*text-align: inherit; optinal*/
}

.centerStyle{
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Edit: Align only one cell**

Declare a new grid just for the cell you want to align:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" width="800px">
    <h:outputText  value="#test" />
    <h:outputText  value="#test" />
    <h:panelGrid columnClasses="centerStyle" width="100px">
        <h:outputText  value="#test" />
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:outputText  value="#test" />
    <h:outputText  value="#test" />
    <h:outputText value="#test" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: We can align whole column using columnClasses. But my need is to align a particular cell of a column.